# Casting in Java for ListIterator

Tags: java, casting, listiterator

I am not sure why there is need for casting in the code below. Any insight? It doesn't make sense to me why this is needed. I appreciate any help as always!

```
public class ListIterator<E> implements java.util.Iterator<E>{
    private Predecessor <E> prev;
    private Predecessor <E> node;

public ListIterator(LinkedList<E> list{
    prev = null;
    node = list;
}

public boolean hasNext(){
    returnnode.getNext() !=null;
}

public E next(){
    prev = node;
    node = node.getNext();
    return ((ListNode.<E>)node).getItem();
}

public void remove(){
    prev.setNext(node.getNext());
    node = prev;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Predecessor`? Btw can you fix the syntax errors in your current code, please? :)

Comment: I'm guessing the ```Predecessor.getItem()``` method returns an Object, thus the need for the cast.

Comment: @Siddhartha Wrong guess. The cast applies **before**  anything is called on node. The reason must be that the class "Predecessor" is not a subclass of Node ...

Comment: So should this be made into a parent class?

Comment: Sorry Tom, broken finger...Trying to type my best...

Comment: @AdamDiStefano Care to put some Predecessor or ListNode code?

Comment: @AdamDiStefano You don't need  to rewrite your code here. Just copy and paste the code from your IDE :).

Comment: It is from a text. I cannot get my head around OOP for the life of me

Comment: The request remains, please add the code of `Predecessor` and `ListNode` to your question.